# Android - Fit a TextView in a circle drawable background

Tags: java, android, textview, geometry

I have a square FrameLayout with a circle background.

In another FrameLayout (over the other one), I have a TextView of 2 lines (that can be converted to 2 TextViews if necessary).

I want the TextView to fit more or less in the background circle but I didn't find a way to achieve that and each time I use paddings or something, in a few devices I have the expected result.

EDIT : here's what I want to achieve:

[image]

The problem is depending on the device I test the app, the result is different, sometimes it overfills the circle...

Comment: Please show what you want and what you have.

Comment: Of course, check my update

Comment: if I get you right. You want so that the text is adjusted to the shape of a circle. If it is true then your task non-trivial. FrameLayout (parent view) has the form of a rectangle. And regardless of background TextView (child view) will draw text in rectangle. what can be done? You can find lib for this case or create custom view which draw text in circle shape.